# Replace only images and tags with surgical precision that match an img list var

Tags: php, html, regex

OK my goal is to remove all images and their tags that I specify in an array or group, it should remove the entire image and tags and work if its contained in a link or not.

so far I got this working somewhat but far from perfect this version only removes images not in an href tag, i need it to work both ways.

so if we have `<img src="test1.gif" width="235">` it must remove that even if it contains other code and even if its surrounded by a link as long as the image name matches.

So any images contained in the group must be completely removed with there tags and or links that wrap that image contained in my var.

This is what I have so far.
`#<img[^>]+src=".*?(test1.gif|test2.png|test3.jpg)"[^>]+>?#i`

Ultimately what I am trying to do is not as simple as I hoped so I am hopping some regex guru's can help with this task as I cant find anything on here or the net most are just replacing all images on a page not specific images. Not my reason for it needing to be a Regex is because this must work in other code that's based around preg_replace and yes, I know thats not the best way to do it.

UPDATED added this as example sorry for any confusion.

This all PHP Based!

So this var will have all the images that we need to replace. with nothing.

$m_rimg = "imagewatever.gif|test.jpg|animage.png";
`preg_replace('#<img[^>]+src=".*?('.$m_rimg.')"[^>]+>?#i','');`

This almost works but not correctly as it must also remove images wrapped in a link href tag and remove the image along with the link if it has one.  so basically I need what I have modified to work correctly with `<img src="whatever.gif" width="">` or `<a href="www.testthis.net"><img src="whatever.gif" width=""></a>` but it must only replace or remove the images that match in the var list not just replacing all images, that are images ... that I can do this is more complex.

I hope this better explains it.

UPDATED 04/25/15
Ok I tried the last one that was added to test it out info below.

I had to mod it with some \ so i did not get parse error so for anyone looking to do something similar to my needs.

This worked great. I just modded what you gave me like this.
`"#(?:<a\b[^>]*?>)?(<img[^>]+src=[\"'][^>]*?($m_rimg)['\"][^>]*>)(?:<\/a>)?#is"`

and did not use preg_quote, not sure why but that did not work at all but without preg_quote it works so far in some tests i just did.

I was told to not use | but that is what seems to work how else would you guys suggest?

As to this being a duplicate of another answered question flagged by some, I do not think that's the case as I looked at what is said to be the answer to my question as well and it is not the same that I see at all, and is not doing the exact thing I need to do match whats in my var. while yes it is Regex related it did not help, I tried to find something on here that worked for my needs, way before ever posting.

I got a helpful answer to my problem from one user, who understood why I was doing it this way. I hope this is now acceptable to lift he dupe status as my goal was not to offend those who don't think I should use a Regex as part of an HTML parser script.

Comment: You say you know this is not the best way to do it.... why do it this way, then? The reason it isn't the best way, as you noted, is because it is not reliable. Regex isn't made to parse HTML, and you'll find many edge cases that prove this blanket statement to be true. If you're using javascript, use DOM to examine nodes. If you're using PHP, use DomDocument. Other languages have tools that are designed to parse HTML, and that's what you ought to use -- the tool designed for the job. Which isn't Regex.

Comment: sorry having problems using this  That did not work at all the way i need it to let me explain this works within a script that I have and calls a function where it takes what is parsed and then passes it to a series of regexe's.  not sure why i cant hit return on here it posts half my sentences.

I need this moded so that it will remove the images and there tags even if the image is wrapped in an href.   

this is the group var it can be any images in this list 
 `$m_rimg = "test.gf|whatever.jpg|test2.png";  
preg_replace("/<img[^>]+src=[\"'].*?\\.('.$m_rimg.')['\"][^>]*>/is","");`

Comment: @Chris Baker how is what I asked a duplicate I saw no answers to exactly what I was trying to do anywhere on this site ... I needed to remove only what was on a list via my var, not all images and not just images but surgically remove only the images and the tags such as the href that may or may not be wrapping an image as a link. I got one answer that addressed my question and how to do it so why is my question flagged. If i am missing something please show me where this exact problem was answered.

Comment: I know I shouldn't use a wrench to bang in a nail I get that part, but all I needed was to mod a few lines that are in an existing script and they are Regex based, I am not trying to redo the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadXML('HTML_DOCUMENT');

$list = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($list as $img){
    $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    //only match if src contains `test1.gif`:
    if(stringEndsWith($src, 'test1.gif') ||
       stringEndsWith($src, 'test2.gif') ||
       stringEndsWith($src, 'test3.gif')) {
        $list->removeChild($img);
    }
}

function stringEndsWith($haystack, $ending, $caseInsensitivity = false)
{
    if ($caseInsensitivity)
        return strcasecmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($ending)), $haystack) === 0;
    else
        return strpos($haystack, $ending, strlen($haystack) - strlen($ending)) !== false;
}
```

Or as you state you still need a regex way to remove `<img>` tags based on the alternative list inside a `$m_rimg` variable, and any `<a>` tags wrapped around, so use this:

```
$re = "#(?:<a\b[^>]*?>)?(<img[^>]+src=["'][^>]*?('.$m_rimg.')['"][^>]*>)(?:<\/a>)?#is"; 
$str = "<img\n att=\"value\"\n src=\"sometext3456..,gjyg&&&test1.gif\" />\n\n<a href=\"link.html\"><img src=\"imagewatever.gif\"></a>"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

Mind that all the items in your variable must be `preg_quote`d, but not the `|` symbols.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL7nR7/2)

Comment: I really need a Regex as it must work with other code already in use the main page parsing code is already in place and works via preg_replace.

Comment: That did not work at all the way i need it to let me explain this works withing a script that call a function where it takes what is parsed and then passes it to a series of regexes I need this one modded so that it will remove the images and there tags even if the image is wrapped in an href.

Comment: Please add some examples, some sample input to test against, to the question body.

Comment: I find this forum dificult to use bare with me it keeps cutting me off and only gives 5 mins ok this is PHP thats what I need the regex in. can somone tell me why I cant use return key? how do you space on this forum.

Comment: This all PHP Based!

So this var will have all the images that we need to replace. with nothing.
$m_rimg = "imagewatever.gif|test.jpg|animage.png";

This almost works but not correctly as it must also remove images wrapped in a link and remove the image along with the link if it has one.  I hope this better explains it.
`preg_replace('#<img[^>]+src=".*?('.$m_rimg.')"[^>]+>?#i','');`

Comment: Do you mean you need to remove also `<a>` tags around `<img>` tag if they meet your criteria? Like `<a href="link.html"><img src="imagewatever.gif"></a>`? Try `#(?:<a\b[^>]*?>)?(<img[^>]+src=["'][^>]*?('.$m_rimg.')['"][^>]*>)(?:<\/a>)?#is`, but you should use `preg_quote` on each item (not the whole resulting string!) when constructing your `$m_rimg` value.

Comment: yes but only if they exist they may in many cases not be there but if they are then yes I am sure this is pos but i cant figure out how to code it. right now what I wrote works kind of it does selectively remove images that i add to the list but its not perfect at all, it sometimes will remove something next to it  and make the rest of the page as long href and that's bad, so if at the least you can mod what I do have to make it 100 time better then what I have that would be great.

Comment: I updated the info in my question please see that and I want to thank you for your help on this because i could not find anything that did exactly what I needed in the way I needed. even though the sys here says there may be an answer or something sim but nothing that I saw.

Comment: Glad to hear you finslly found a way to make the regex work. The pipe symbol should be used when you have a list. Just do not escape this pipe. What you should escape is each element of this list as `.` will match any character. If you pass `file...png` to the regex, fileRR.png` will also be matched. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks man your regex is like gold you rock. my need was dif then others have asked, as most just want to remove all images. That is simple but what i needed was more complex to match only a list and you nailed it. this was actually needed to mod a mobile site parsing script encase anyone was wondering. as is the script was worthless but with all my mods ideas and your regex its all coming together ... So now it works as was required.

Comment: Cool, please consider accepting the answer then (a tick on the left below the upvote number.)

Comment: I accepted the answer but it will not yet let me tick the up-vote button, I guess its cause im too new to posting questions on this forum ... This is the first I have posted. I will post more now that I understand how this sys works. Thanks again.

Comment: @user4829773 This regex might work.... until it doesn't. Don't use Regex to parse HTML. Bad practice. You say you have a reason, your reason is wrong.

Comment: @Chris Baker while I know what your saying this is part of a parser that I did not write I am just modifying what I have. If you would like to completely recode what I have so it does not use any regex great I can send you the code if you want it. or I can tell you where to find it on googlecode,I was just trying to get help with what I had ideas on how to accomplish. Not make people uptite that I am using a regex to do it.

Comment: @user4829773 The first part of this answer shows you how to do it correctly -- with the tool in PHP made to parse HTML. Someone already wrote the code. In javascript, you would use a different approach, because it is a different language in a different environment. DOM manipulation is what javascript is for: you've got `document.getElementsByTagName`, or a library like jQuery. I'm not uptight -- this is a q/a site for reference solutions, not a personal help forum. The goal is to help the **next guy** solve the same problem, and a regex solution is bad content because it is wrong :)

Comment: @Chris Baker Ya lost me, a came for an answer that works for me, the first may be fine for you or absolutely correct if I was starting from scratch, but I am not I am working with existing code that uses funcs that work with what I asked I just needed to mod the way it works and nothing here was exactly as I needed. The tool you show would require a complete recode of what I have. So it was not a solution for me right or wrong.